# How to Contract a Loop?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following proposition below (it can be found [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Matrices.pdf) on p. 6 too where it specifically states that the proposition holds with loops and multiple edges).

> **Question:** How do you contract a loop? I thought $G-e=G/e$ when $e$ is a loop. However, it is clear that $t(G/e)=0$ when $e$ is a loop to make the proposition below hold true.

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a graph. Then, for any edge $e$, $t(G)=t(G-e)+t(G/e)$ .

> As for *notation*, I assume graphs allow repeated edges and loops, and the notation $t(G)$ denotes the number of spanning trees of $G$. Also, $G-e$ denotes the deletion of edge $e$ and $G/e$ denotes the contraction of edge $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to make sense of it is to say that $G/e$ *is not defined* if $e$ is a loop, and that the proposition does not claim anything in that case.

This requires doing a bit of violence to the wording, but produces something that is true and still useful, because you'll never need to apply it to loops in order to make progress anyway.

---

Alternatively you can say that you work only with multigraphs *without* loops and define contraction such that it removes *all* edges parallel to the one you contract.